# Importing bitmap in Dia

Tags: import, png, dia

I am having a .png file listing some workflows and I need to edit it and add new  workflows to it using Dia. Is there an option to import .png file and make it editable in dia ? If not any other option for me so that I can edit the file

Comment: question should be on [su]. anyway check http://dia-installer.de/doc/en/loadsave-chapter.html#loadsave-filetypes-import import is possible but you get only a bitmap, not the diagram with editable nodes

Answer (score 11):

You have two choices:

a) Add your PNG as a an image to your Dia diagram - see

http://dia-installer.de/doc/en/basic-objects-chapter.html#image

Once you've done that, you can "draw over" the image. Place a white rectangle over parts that you don't need. Dia allows you to change the order of the object (you want to place the image in the background). Dia also supports "Layers" to organize your objects. You could add your image to a background layer to ensure that it stays in the background. This is the quick and dirty approach.

b) Convert your PNG into a vector graphic (SVG) and import that into Dia. Dia does not support this conversion, but you could use Inkscape to do that. This approach is more sophisticated and will require a good quality PNG that is suited for conversion.
http://inkscape.org/

Comment: And when a) importing the PNG, don't forget to set "Inline data" to "Yes" in image properties otherwise Dia will only add a link to the image and if the image file is deleted (or renamed) you will see only "Broken image" in your diagram.